# Toggle Animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Home button.  When it is clicked, About will show up (animation) and when I click the Home button again, About will go back.  I want to create toggle animation, an issue is About is showing up, but not go back.

Need your help.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wpgcurv/)

```js
var main = function() {
  $('#hme').click(function() {
    if ($('#abt').css('left', '-60px'))
      $('#abt').animate({
        left: '200px'
      }, 300);
    else
      $('#abt').animate({
        left: '-60px'
      }, 300);
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
#abt {
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  top: 50px
}

#nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

#navLst {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: color .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='bckDrp'>
  <div id='nav'>
    <ul id='navLst'>
      <li class='navOp' id='hme'>Home</li>
      <li class='navOp' id='abt'>About</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin-left` instead of `left` like the code below

```js
var main = function() {
      $('#hme').click(function(){
        if($('#abt').css("margin-left") == "200px"){
           $('#abt').animate({"margin-left": '-=200'});
        }  
       else{
            $('#abt').animate({"margin-left": '+=200'}); 
       }
            
      });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
#abt {
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  top: 50px
}

#nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
}

#navLst {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: color .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='bckDrp'>
      <div id='nav'>
        <ul id='navLst'>
          <li class='navOp' id='hme'>Home</li>
          <li class='navOp' id='abt'>About</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Amine, Thank you very much for your input that works so well!  Would you please let me know the difference between `css("margin-left") == "200px")` and `css("margin-left", "200px"))` in my `if statement`?  I tried `css("margin-left", "200px"))`, it didn't work, but `css("margin-left") == "200px")` works right away.

Comment: if statement waite a boolean `if(bool)` that's why we've tried to check if `css("margin-left") == "200px")` is true or false, but this `css("margin-left", "200px"))` jus set margin-left to 200px, i hope you have understood me :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're setting the css value for `#abt` instead of checking it. Try this:

```
var main = function(){
  $('#hme').click(function(){
    var left = $('#abt').css('left');
    if(left == '-60px') {
        $('#abt').animate({left: '200px'},300 );
    } else {
        $('#abt').animate({left: '-60px'},300 );
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: Great! :) please award a correct answer / upvote if you've found a solution.

Comment: I wanted to vote for both, but how can I vote for both answers?  They are all great solutions!

Comment: You can use the up arrow icons next to the big number next to each answer to vote.